# Multiple order_by not ordering by correctly in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

Attempting to order by two columns in the following query. I want to find the nearest people and then order by the highest ranking.

When I run this query however, it only returns the nearest people and does not applying the second ordering

```
SELECT person.fullname, person.ranking_score ranking, ST_Distance(person.location, CAST(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.1642618, 51.58763), 4326) AS geography(GEOMETRY,-1))) AS distance
FROM person
ORDER BY distance ASC, ranking DESC;
```

returns

```
 fullname |  ranking   |   distance    
----------+------+------------+-------
 User 1   |    2.62    | 1281.06710415
 User 2   |    5.218   | 1610.4042403
 User 3   |    3.72    | 3005.28625016
 User 4   |    2.82    | 3005.28625016
 User 5   |    6.826   | 3186.54245429
```

As you can see the correct ordering is applied to the distance, but not to the ranking too.

EDIT:

I expected that the initial ordering of distance would be applied and then the next ordering would be applied to that result set?

```
 fullname |  ranking   |   distance    
----------+------+------------+-------
 User 5   |    6.826   | 3186.54245429
 User 2   |    5.218   | 1610.4042403
 User 3   |    3.72    | 3005.28625016
 User 4   |    2.82    | 3005.28625016
 User 1   |    2.62    | 1281.06710415
```

Comment: The second argument (ranking) will only be considered when two (or more) distances are the same. (See user 3 and user 4.)

Comment: the sorting is correct. what is your expected output?

Comment: Just edited my answer detailing my expected output?

Comment: No, the data is ordered in the order of columns specified in the ORDER BY clause. If two rows have tie for the values in first column, the tie is broken by looking at values in 2nd column and so on.

Answer (score 1):

For your sample data, you want to order by the ranking first:

```
SELECT p.fullname, p.ranking_score ranking, 
       ST_Distance(p.location, CAST(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-0.1642618, 51.58763), 4326) AS geography(GEOMETRY,-1))) AS distance
FROM person p
ORDER BY ranking DESC, distance ASC;
```

I suspect that in your real problem you would have either a condition limiting the distance or want to fetch a certain number of rows of the nearest people  The latter case requires a subquery.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification and the subquery sounds like a good option. Ideally it would be great to retrieve an initial result set containing all people within a certain distance and then ranking by score. This is what I thought the initial query would do.